# How do I prove that a conditionally convergent series can diverge to infinity under a suitable rearrangement?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I can prove a conditionally convergent series can be made to converge to any real number ( using the idea of adding just enough positive terms to get to the number then adding just enough negative terms etc) but im not sure how to show it can be made to diverge to infinity under a suitable rearrangement.

Comment: Add positive terms to exceed 1. Add the first negative term. Add positive terms to exceed 2. Add the second negative term. ...

Comment: First show that for a series that converges conditionally, both its non-positive and non-negative parts diverge.